# Scraping from webpage - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am very new to web programming using python. Currently I am working on something to "scrape" a small piece of information from a website.
Website: http://www.airport-data.com/airport/HJO/#location
Information to extract/scrap: "Elevation" (see under Location & QuickFacts)

The code I have so far:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
url2 = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.airport-data.com/airport/HJO/#location').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(url2)
print soup #I did this just to see the content.
```

I tried to read online and looked at some previous posts but failed to wrap my head around. Any suggestions on how can I proceed to extract/scrape "Elevation" from the weblink?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, according to the [`BeautifulSoup` project documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html):

> Beautiful Soup 3 has been replaced by Beautiful Soup 4.
>
> Beautiful Soup 3 only works on Python 2.x, but Beautiful Soup 4 also
>   works on Python 3.x. Beautiful Soup 4 is faster, has more features,
>   and works with third-party parsers like lxml and html5lib. You should
>   use Beautiful Soup 4 for all new projects.

Install [`BeautifulSoup` 4-th version](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
pip install beautifulSoup4
```

Then, the idea would be to find the tag containing `Elevation:` text and get [the next sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url2 = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.airport-data.com/airport/HJO/#location')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url2)

print soup.find('td', class_='tc1', text='Elevation:').next_sibling.text
```

Prints:

```
240 ft / 73.15 m (Estimated)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did `soup.find('td', class_='tc0', text='Longitude/Latitude:').next_sibling.text` and it is extracting the content. But `'Longitude/Latitude:'` has two lines separated by `<br>` and how do I extract just the second line i.e., content after `<br>`? (I can have the second line by string manipulation but wondering if I can extract WITHOUT string manipulation)

Comment: @SrinGupta sure, `print soup.find('td', text='Longitude/Latitude:').next_sibling.contents[2]` should do it.